# Download Urls From Xml Sitemaps Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, caching, powershell-2.0

I have a standard XML sitemap on a few different sites. http://example.com/sitemap, http://otherexample.com etc...

In the standard format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1"
        xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0">

    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.co.uk</loc>
        <lastmod>2014-07-08T08:28:26+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.3</priority>
    </url>


    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.co.uk/page-name</loc>
        <lastmod>2013-02-05T13:36:02+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.7</priority>
    </url>

     etc....

</urlset>
```

I'd like to be able to provide a list of urls for the sitemaps. And have a powershell file go off to each site individually.

Get the sitemap xml for each site, and then download all the urls individually from the sitemap file. Basically making a request to each url (I don't want to store the contents of the download).

The idea is it will trigger the cache for all the main pages for each site after a site update, so when users hit the site they have a cached version.

Any ideas on how I might go about this? I started to try and use Wget but had issues on Win8/Server. So thought Powershell might be a better option.

Comment: you should have provide a minimum code from yourself...

Comment: Why? Where does it state in StackOverFlow that I have to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

if youc can run powerhell V3 here is a way :
`iwr` is an alias of `invoke-webrequest`

```
$maps=@("http://server.com/sitemap.xml","http://server2.com/sitemap.xml")
$maps |%{
    [xml]$response=iwr $_ |select -expand content
    #get all urls in the sitemap
    $response.urlset.url |%{
        #make a get request on each url
        echo "hitting : " $_.loc
        iwr $_.loc |out-null

    }
}
```

if you can't switch to V3, you will have to use the .net method, replace the iwr whith the following pattern :

```
$client=New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
[xml]$response=$client.DownloadString("http://server.com/sitemap.xml")
```